# Разработка Ftp клиента

Tags: ftp, c++

Делаю лабораторную "ftp client". Когда посылаю серверу "LIST", в массив приходит список папок и файлов в виде:

> drwxrwxrwx 1 user group 11 May 10 23:12 !! Папка1drwxrwxrwx 1 user
> group 22 May 10 12:11 !! Песня1...

Ниже, в функцию передаю массив с указанными выше данными в виде длинной строки и, если ее сразу выводить в listBox1, то он почему то не видит '\n', поэтому приходится выводить через `strtok()`:

```
void СhToSysStr(char* ch) 
{
    char* tok;
    tok = strtok(ch,"\n");
    while(tok)          
    {                         
        String^ str = gcnew String(tok);
        listBox1->Items->Add(str);
        tok = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
}
```

После чего получается:

> drwxrwxrwx 1 user group 11 May 10 23:12 !! Папка1
>
> drwxrwxrwx 1 user group 22 May 10 12:11 !! Песня1
>
> drwxrwxrwx 1 user group 25 May 10 21:33 !! Видео1
> ...

Как можно вывести в listBox1 только имена Папка1 и т.д.?

> Папка1
>
> Фильм
>
> Музыка
>
> ...

Притом, что длина строки перед именем папки может быть разной.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь командой nlst, вместо list. Она как раз вернет только имена.

Comment: Спасибо , помогло , но почемуто на некоторых  фтп NLST выводит имена фалов и папок , а на некоторых в ответ на NLST ничего не присылает(точнее в мой buff[65356]="" приходит пустой ответ ), а на LIST нормально реагируют , только приходят имена с правами доступа , датой создания итд. Почему так?

Comment: У ftp довольно 'скользкий' rfc. Тем не менее команда list не предназначена для программной обработки, согласно все тому же rfc 959 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt